# center horizontally 2 elements in a row using bootstrap or css

Tags: html, css, row

Im using a bootstrap template and I need to center two element in the team section. 
The elements are inside a div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" and this one is inside a div class="team-top" and this one is inside a div class="row". I'm still kinda newbie with bootstrap so I find difficult to find which classes I have to modify.
Each element has an image and text describing each one of the team members.

[actual situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGLlp.png)

here's the code.

```
  <div id="team" class="our-team-area area-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="section-headline text-center">
            <h2>Nuestro Equipo</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="team-top">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="single-team-member">
              <div class="team-img">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/team/1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
                <div class="team-social-icon text-center">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="team-content text-center">
                <h4>Daniel Cárdenas</h4>
                <p>Músico, Ingeniero en y Cofundador de Conectarte Studio</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="single-team-member">
              <div class="team-img">
                <a href="#">
                                        <img src="img/team/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                <div class="team-social-icon text-center">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                                </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                                </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                                </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="team-content text-center">
                <h4>Ignacio Weisser</h4>
                <p>Músico, Ingeniero en Sonido y Cofundador de Conectarte Studio</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End column -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Team Area -->
```

I've tried

```
.team-top{
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.team-top{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.team-top{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

and adding classes to div class="row" and div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" and div class="single-team-member" but I still believe I have to add CSS to div class="team-top"

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position or reorder columns in a bootstrap row, you can use Push, Pull or Offset ([bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-responsive-resets)).

Offset adds a left margin to a column.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12"></div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12"> did the job. Thank you so much!!